# I am having hard time proving following function is bijective? Help

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$Q: \text{map}(B,A) \times \text{map}(C,A) \to \text{map}(B \cup C, A)$ be function defined by $Q(f,g)=f \cup g$
This is what i have so far,
Claim: $Q$ is injeective
Proof: Let $(f,g)$ and $(e,h)$ be in $\text{map}(B,A) \times \text{map}(C,A)$.Asuume $Q(f,g)=Q(e,h)$ Then by definition of $Q$,
$$
\begin{align}
        Q(f,g) &=Q(e,h), \\
         f \cup g &= e \cup h.
\end{align}
$$

here is where i m having problem i cant directly say they are equal. And i have no idea to prove it surjective. Please help me.

Comment: You have to assume that $B$ and $C$ are disjoint.

Comment: yes they are disjoint

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Two functions $f,g$ with the same domain $X$ are equal if and only if for all $x\in X$, $f(x)=g(x)$. Suppose that $Q(f_1,g_1)=Q(f_2,g_2)=h$, restrict $h$ back to $B$ and $C$ and show that this restriction must be $f_1$ and $g_1$ respectively.

The same idea will also show that $Q$ is surjective, but this time you need to start with an arbitrary $h$, rather than one particularly taken from the range of $Q$.

Comment: I am sorry but I dont get it.

Comment: Get what?${}{}$

Comment: The injective part. do you mean i have to show f=e and g=h ?

Comment: I revised my hint, I hope it's better now.

Comment: so u mean Q(f,g) = some function h in Map(BUC,A). Since f is some function from B to A and g is some function from C to A. This is so confusing. Not your fault.Can u explain it little more plz. I really appreciate ur help.

Comment: I'm not sure what your comment is intended to say, but even if you are writing from a cellphone - try and use proper English.

Comment: Just to be straight forward, i just want to say ur hints doesnt make any sense to me.